# Excel 365 - Create new table from existing one to normalize monthly data into separate rows

Tags: excel, pivot, powerquery, transpose, excel-365

I have a dataset that has sales information with column headers like these:

```
Item# |   Measure  |  Jan |   Feb |   Mar |   *etc.*
```

I need to transform the table to where each item number row contains the type of measure, month, and values for each measure. So it will look like this:

```
Item# |   Month  |  Measure_1 |   Measure_2 |   Measure_3 |   *etc.*
```

I have tried to unpivot in Power Query and the results are either null or come back skewed.  Also, I have tried to consolidate multiple ranges with pivot tables and the data doesn't line up right. Perhaps there is a python or SQL query I could run in Power BI to get this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Power Query like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQ0MDA1VtJRCkotSczMATJMTS2BpKG5sQWQMjc1BZFmlkqxOkiK3XMTi9Iz84AsY2MQ39zSAEiamBqBSXNUxaF5mSXFIIPNgISRsQnYWBCBpi48NTM9owRkN0jWzBCk2gBCoKhzLk1KBakCGQmlDZViYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Item#" = _t, Type = _t, Jan = _t, Feb = _t, Mar = _t, Apr = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item#", Int64.Type}, {"Type", type text}, {"Jan", Int64.Type}, {"Feb", Int64.Type}, {"Mar", Int64.Type}, {"Apr", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Item#", "Type"}, "Month", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Columns"[Type]), "Type", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

The following two rows do the trick:

```
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Item#", "Type"}, "Month", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Columns"[Type]), "Type", "Value", List.Sum)
```

Source:
[image]
Result:
[image]